# phonegap/web database errorcodes Explanation?

Tags: javascript, database, cordova, web-storage

I want to show correct errors to the user if a transaction with a web database (I´m using Phonegap) fails. In the Error-Callback I ask for the error.code value to determine what went wrong.

The Documentations says [this](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.2.0/phonegap_storage_storage.md.html#SQLError) about it. However, I have a case where the transaction fails because a unique constraint is violated by inserting a value that already exists.

```
function saveErrorCB(err){
    console.log(err.code + " " + err.message + " ");
}
```

err.code shows:

> 1

err.message shows here:

> could not execute statement (19 constraint failed)

My point is, I want to know about other codes like "1". The Phonegap documentation doesnt mention it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the Phonegap documentation does (eventually) link to a W3C page which then says...

- UNKNOWN_ERR = 0
- DATABASE_ERR = 1
- VERSION_ERR = 2
- TOO_LARGE_ERR = 3
- QUOTA_ERR = 4
- SYNTAX_ERR = 5
- CONSTRAINT_ERR = 6
- TIMEOUT_ERR = 7

It seems `err.message` is more useful - thanks for telling me about it!